# Why is key required in constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have created class which extend `StatefulWidget`

```
class RegistrationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String email;

  const RegistrationPage({Key key, required this.email}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegistrationPage createState() => _RegistrationPage();
}
```

The problem is android studio force me to put `required` before `Key key`. I googled some of examples how to pass values from screen to another screen and I have never seen that someone used required with Key.
I do it within:

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => RegistrationPage(email: email),
        ),
      );
```

so just to pass email value. I need to make Key nullable to make it work.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Key is expected to be nullable. The widget super constructors use a nullable key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're using null-safe Dart and `key` can't be `null` because it has a non-nullable type `Key`.

**Solutions:**

- Use `required`

  ```dart
  FooPage({required Key key});
  ```
- Make `key` nullable.

  ```dart
  FooPage({Key? key});
  ```
- Remove `key` altogether.

  ```dart
  FooPage();
  ```

Comment: Which one is better. I know that I need to add '`?' or `required`

Comment: @traki111 If you are definitely going to use `key`, use `required`, if definitely not, remove the `key` and if you're not sure use `Key?`. I've provided all the three possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I think your project is in null safety, with null safety a variable or object cannot be null execept if it is declared nullable.
Try adding a `?` after `Key`:

```
class RegistrationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String email;

  const RegistrationPage({Key? key, required this.email}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegistrationPage createState() => _RegistrationPage();
}
```

or you can simply delete the Key override:

```
class RegistrationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String email;

  const RegistrationPage({required this.email});

  @override
  _RegistrationPage createState() => _RegistrationPage();
}
```

I suggest you to read https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: but it is fine if I remove Key? Everything will works like it should?

Comment: @traki111 Yes unless you're planning on using keys, you don't need it.

Comment: yes, if you have no use for key it will work without any override

Comment: @traki111 please look at the link in my answer to understand more about null safety. All flutter projects from now will default to null safety.

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong by making `Key key` nullable. The [`super`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget/Widget.html) constructors that you're passing the key to accept the nullable type.

So

```dart
const RegistrationPage({Key? key, required this.email}) : super(key: key);
```

is the norm as there is no reason to constrain the type by making it non-nullable and required.

If you have no need for keys with this widget, you can omit the `super` constructor and the `key` parameter completely.